# Is it possible to make each MediaWiki revision page unique?

Tags: api, version-control, mediawiki, revision

I have an extension that saves data to a specific page url (i.e: /index.php). Let's say I go into revision mode within the MediaWiki page and I set back the changes I made 13 days ago. The extension still shows the data saved to index.php, which isn't data that really belongs to the older version of the page but the new one so it becomes an issue. I am very limited to make adjustments to the extension, that's why I was wondering if there is a way that I can do it within MediaWiki. Maybe give each revision page a unique url (index81239014.php or something)? I don't know, I am just guessing. Hope someone can help me out

I've tried adjusting the extension but the possibilities are very limited

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Can you rephrase? Or maybe explain what you are trying to achieve with your extension?

Comment: Let me rephrase and simplify:

I need to request the root url of the page, so if index.php/main_page?edit=12314 then I only want index.php/main_page.

There is a magic word for it: https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Page_names titled {{ROOTPAGENAME}} but I need to request it in an external .php file.

Comment: Where do you get the URL from? Sounds like you are approaching some simple problem from a difficult direction.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP equivalent of the magic word [`{{ROOTPAGENAME}}`](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Page_names) is [`Title::getRootText()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classTitle.html#a79a8d1344f32cb2a4a356046e8b50aae). You may also be interested in the [equivalent HTTP API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Info).

If you want a URL, then you want one of the functions from Title.php, sometime after [line 1875](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/Title_8php_source.html#l01875), which are documented at https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classTitle.html